# I try to overload the >> operator for an object but I get some errors. Why ? C++

Tags: c++, overloading

I try to overload >> operator but I get some errors. What can be wrong ?

```
class Holiday {
public:
    friend ifstream& operator >> (ifstream&
    st, const Holiday& h) {
        st >> h.id ;
        st >> h.dest ;
        st >> h.type;
        st >> h.price;
        return stream;
}

protected:
    int id;
    string dest;
    string type;
    int price;
};
```

Comment: What errors are you encountering?  What is `stream`?

Answer (score 2):

Remove qualifier const in the parameter declaration

```
const Holiday& h
```

Also you have to return st

```
return st;
```

Also it would be better if the function were declared as

```
friend istream& operator >> (istream& st, Holiday& h){
```

Comment: There's at least one other clear error I see, but I admit to overlooking the one you found

Comment: I did this but it still give me errors like :Multiple markers at this line
 - 'std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, 
  _Traits>'
 - no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}' 
  and 'int')
 - candidates are:
 - 'std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<char, 
  _Traits>'

Comment: @user3662714 See my updated post. Use std::istream instead of std::ifstream.

Comment: Also,  how should I call the operator for a Holiday* h object.?
 I tried :

    Holiday* h;
 in >>h;
but it gives some errors. Please help.

Comment: @user3662714 Why do you use a pointer? You could write simply Holiday h; in >> h;

Comment: because I want to store them in a list of pointers. Is it possible  ?

Comment: also you need `#include <istream>`  (and `#include <fstream>` if you really did want `ifstream` rather than `istream` )

Comment: i have all the includes

Comment: @user3662714 _'i have all the includes'_ `#include <string>` also??

Comment: @user3662714. If you need a pointer then write  Holiday *h = new Holiday(); in >> *h;